# JDBC - Retrieve Boolean output from Oracle Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, boolean, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I need to invoke an Oracle procedure with one IN parameter with VARCHAR2 and OUT parameter as BOOLEAN data type.

**Below is my code using SimpleJdbcCall**

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(getTemplate()) 
            .withCatalogName("package_name")
            .withProcedureName("proc_name")
            .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
            .declareParameters(
                new SqlParameter ("userName", Types.VARCHAR), 
                new SqlOutParameter("status", Types.BOOLEAN)
            );                  
Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
inParams .put("userName",  userInput);
Map<String, Object> outputValue= jdbcCall.execute(inParams);
```

> Exception : CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for
>   SQL [{call PACKAGE_NAME.PROC_NAME(?, ?)}]; SQL state [99999];
>   error code [17004]; Invalid column type: 16; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 16

After doing a research i found that "*JDBC drivers do not support the passing of Boolean parameters to PL/SQL stored procedures*"

It has been suggested to wrap the PL/SQL procedure with a second PL/SQL procedure. The main problem is that i am restricted for write access in the db as that is client data. please help me to fix this issue.

**Some of the links i referred**

1. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64685/tips3.htm
2. https://community.oracle.com/thread/2139408?tstart=0
3. https://community.oracle.com/thread/887712?tstart=0
4. https://community.oracle.com/thread/975159?tstart=0
5. [Stored Function - Sending/Receiving Boolean - BD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432192/stored-function-sending-receiving-boolean-bd)
6. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/apxtblsh.htm#i1005380

Answer (score 4):

From the official Oracle [JDBC documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#JJDBC28928):

> It is not feasible for Oracle JDBC drivers to support calling
>   arguments or return values of the PL/SQL RECORD, BOOLEAN, or table
>   with non-scalar element types. [...] As a workaround to PL/SQL RECORD,
>   BOOLEAN, or non-scalar table types, create container procedures that
>   handle the data as types supported by JDBC. For example, to wrap a
>   stored procedure that uses PL/SQL boolean, create a stored procedure
>   that takes a character or number from JDBC and passes it to the
>   original procedure as BOOLEAN or, for an output parameter, accepts a
>   BOOLEAN argument from the original procedure and passes it as a CHAR
>   or NUMBER to JDBC. Similarly, to wrap a stored procedure that uses
>   PL/SQL records, create a stored procedure that handles a record in its
>   individual components, such as CHAR and NUMBER, or in a structured
>   object type.

This is exactly what you did in your answer, but I wanted to add the documentation as reference.

Comment: This documentation is for Oracle 11.  The corresponding Oracle 12 docs has a "Notes and Limitations" section which is similar except it does *not* include this section! So, is it possible under Oracle 12? See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/apxref.htm#JJDBC28925

Comment: Also, this document (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#g1009796) lists BOOLEAN as a supported PL/SQL Type but under _Scalar *Character* Types_ which is weird

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue by writing a wrapper procedure to process the result of the actual procedure and sending back the result as varchar data type .
If any of you find it as wrong approach or if you a have any easy way to fix this, please do share your comments.

**Below is the procedure:**

```
DECLARE 
userName VARCHAR2(13);  
status BOOLEAN;  
result VARCHAR2(13); 

BEGIN 
userName := ?; 
status := NULL; 
package_name.proc_name ( userName, status); 
BEGIN 
IF status THEN result := 'Yes'; 
ELSIF NOT status THEN result := 'No'; 
ELSE result := 'NULL'; 
END IF; 
END; 
COMMIT; 
? := result;
END ;
```

Also instead of simpleJdbcCall, i used CallableStatement for processing this. Refer below:

```
try{
    String wrapperProc= "DECLARE userName VARCHAR2(13);  status  BOOLEAN;  result VARCHAR2(13); BEGIN userName := ?; status := NULL; "+
        "package_name.proc_name ( userName, status ); BEGIN IF status THEN result := 'Yes'; ELSIF NOT status THEN " + 
            "result := 'No'; ELSE result := 'NULL'; END IF; END; COMMIT; ? := result;END ;";
    CallableStatement proc_stmt= null;
    proc_stmt = getTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection().prepareCall(wrapperProc);
    proc_stmt.setString(1, "userName");   
    proc_stmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
    proc_stmt.execute();
    System.out.println("Final Result : "+proc_stmt.getString(2));
} catch(SQLException e){
    System.out.println("SQL Exception : "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception : "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

~~Suriya